# how can i get data from a remote website in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the data from `http://whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp` using JavaScript. How can I do this?

I can get the data from ASP.NET by using WebClient class but how can we get data using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). However, unless the service provides a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) interface, AJAX is limited to getting pages from the same domain as the page it runs on. See: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

The way to get around the same origin policy is to write a script in ASP on your own server that gets the data, and then get that script through AJAX in your page.

Comment: And of course, that will repeatedly tell the original poster the external IP of his own server. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use YQL - http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_html_scraper

It essentially acts as a proxy to grab page data for you through their service. You can interact with it solely with JavaScript.